# How to calculate Gene Ontology terms in python

Tags: sequence-alignment, proteins, networks, protein-protein-interaction

I am testing different `Protein-Protein Interaction networks` alignment tools. I observed that all alignment tools show some `Gene Ontology` terms similarity. How can I calculate `Functional similarity` / `average functional similarity` for `Gene ontology`'s terms `Biological processes`, `Cellular components`, `Molecular functionality` of any two proteins networks

Comment: Welcome.  What tools have you been using?

Comment: hubalign ......

Comment: Do you need it in python? I know one very nice package in R that does that.

Comment: @Llopis it would be nice in python but if any R package you know, kindly mention that

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate gene ontology similarity with the [GOSemSim](http://bioconductor.org/packages/GOSemSim) R package ([paper](http://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btq064))(disclaimer I'm a contributor to this package). You have several similarity scores implemented, some of them are across the three subontologies.

In python you have the [GOATOOLS](https://pypi.org/project/goatools/) ([paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-28948-z)). I think there was another Python package but now I don't remember its name.

Comment: thanks @Llopis. i looked into goatools already but i don't think that they are have methods to calculate GO CC, MF or BP

Comment: Please, mention in the questions what you have done, because now I feel that I wasted my time trying to answer you when your problem is something else. Did you look at the [notebook](https://github.com/tanghaibao/goatools/blob/master/notebooks/semantic_similarity.ipynb) ?

Comment: sorry if you feel that way. but did you saw any GO calculated in goatools ?

Comment: I linked a notebook explaining how they do it..